# Choosing between multinomial logistic regression or binary logistic regression for interchangeable variables

Tags: logistic, estimation, references, multinomial-logit

I want to estimate how likely a disease is associated with symptom (dummy hypothesis). Say that I want to assess which of avian flu, swine flu, and common flu is more commonly associated with fever. In this case, I can use binary logistic regression

However, it's also possible to say that "I want to estimate if fever is more common in avian flu, swine flu, or common flu", in which I should use multinomial logistic regression.

The problem is, if I use multinomial logistic regression, when I use avian flu as the reference and compare avian flu vs common flu, the estimates are different when I invert the reference category i.e., using common flu as the reference category and compare common flu vs avian flu. This makes interpreting the results harder.

In this case, is it valid to use the 1st hypothesis: "which disease is more commonly associated with fever" and use binary logistic regression instead? In that case, changing reference category of independent variables are much easier than changing reference category of dependent variables

Which are the best approach? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you have is `yes/no` for `fever` and distinct categories of `flu`, then you have a 2 x 3 contingency table of counts of the cases in each combination of `fever` presence and `flu` type. In that case, the binary regression of `fever` as a function of `flu` type and the multinomial regression of `flu` type as a function of `fever` presence are just two different ways of looking at the same data set. You can choose the direction you want based on how you want to apply the model.

The usual initial report of regression coefficients for such models leads to the *apparent* problem that you note. Yes, the choice of reference level with more than 2 levels in a categorical variable will affect the reported coefficients, whether the variable is the outcome in a multinomial model for `flu` type or the predictor in a binary model of `fever` outcome.

That's only an *apparent* problem, however. Regardless of your choice of reference level, the model contains all the information needed to evaluate the probability of `fever` given a type of `flu` (or in the other direction, the probability of a `flu` type given presence of `fever`), and to make whatever comparisons among scenarios you wish. For that you can use post-modeling tools like those provided by the R [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans).

Comment: Thanks @EdM for your valuable insights. Yes, in the final model I would also like to include covariates potentially confounding the association, so it's not a direct 2x3 contingency table. In this case, does the premise that both fever x flu and flu x fever are acceptable still valid? Thanks again!

Comment: @amedicalenthusiast the choice is based on what you think of as the "predictor" and what you think of as the "outcome." To my mind, the more useful choice is to have `fever_yes/no` as the outcome, because the multinomial probability of a type of `flu` as a function of presence of `fever` is likely to change as the relative prevalence of different types of `flu` change over time. I suppose, however, that there might be circumstances in which the multinomial `flu_type` outcome could make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I've been wondering